# How to disable data grouping in Highstocks(npm: Angular-highcharts )

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to disable data grouping for a line chart in Highstocks. I'm using angular-highcharts, but it shows error.

[image]

Comment: Hi @pavan skipo, Could you check what the error message is?

Comment: 'dataGrouping' does not exist in type 'SeriesChart' :(

Comment: I recommend you to use Highcharts official wrapper for Angular: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular However, could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? For example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-stock

Comment: @ppotaczek Thanks for the help :), I was able to solve the issue by putting <any> before the object. Actually I cant change the npm module right now, but ill keep in mind to use official wrapper from next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i was able to solve this issue by typecasting chart object to `<any>` .
Hope this helps!

[image]